# Convert datetime to binary data type SQL Server

Tags: binary, type-conversion, sql-server-2016, sqldatatypes, datetime2

I have a value

```
20 01 01 29 13 11 58 15 46 52 00 00 00
```

which got migrated to a SQL Server table of column type `binary` as `0x20010129131158154652000000`. If we observe it is exact value just prefixed with `0x`, which is fine.

Now, when I am trying to insert a value which should be current date and time with 6 precision millisecond it is converting to a hexadecimal value like `0x00000000000000A87200F31D11`.

Please help me find a solution which should give the same time stamp value just by prefixing `0x` even the SQL Server table column type is binary. That is if am passing the value as `2018-01-24 15:08:59.780`, it should insert into SQL Server table of column type `binary(13)` as `0x20180124150859780`

Comment: Can you explain why you would want this?

Comment: This works for `datetime` or `datetime2(>=3)`, but I still don't understand why you'd go to all this trouble instead of just storing it as the right type in the first place: `SELECT CONVERT(binary(13), 
  '0x' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @d, 112)
  + RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(12), @d, 14), ':', ''),'.','')+'0',10)
  , 1);`

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron Bertrand.This worked for me.The reason why I am having this requirement was, I am migrating data and changing database for a particular application from DB2 to SQL server. I have used "SS migration assistant" tool to complete migration from existing db. When I am using insert to scripts for adding new records I am facing issue with the binary data which is getting inserted to sql server.In simple terms there is a inbuilt funtion called Generate_Unique(id) in IBM db2 which will give unique timestamp value in binary format.I am trying to get a similar fx in sqlse also.

Comment: Hi,
In my sql server database as I told in my previous query the time stamp columns are defined as primary key. When I am trying to insert records through insert statement and below function I am not getting unique values. Can someone please suggest me how to achieve unique time stamp values in the SQL Server even when we are inserting hundreds of records as batch through below function? @AaronBertrand please suggest if have any idea about this? My function is in the comments below

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION dbo.unique_id_gen()
Returns Binary(13)
as
Begin

Declare @d datetime2(6), @ret_variable binary(13);
--select SYSDATETIME ();
set @d = SYSDATETIME ();

SET @ret_variable= (SELECT CONVERT(binary(13), '0x' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @d, 112) + RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(16), @d, 14), ':', ''),'.',''),13) , 1))

return(@ret_variable)
END

I am trying to achieve unique values for below sql statment
select dbo.unique_id_gen(),dbo.unique_id_gen(),dbo.unique_id_gen()

Comment: So you want three "random" values based on the time, returned on the same row at a single point in time? Maybe you should stop looking at date/time as the source for your "random" values?

Comment: @AaronBertrand :The value shouldn't be random but next millisecond i meant to say if am getting 0x20180129140405743175000000,next  function call should give0x20180129140417333176000000,following 0x20180129140427603173000000.but, should give as unique value as possible in terms of milliseconds.

Comment: @AaronBertrand:I am even checking the possible option of adding a sequence after 3 precision milliseconds which would uniquely generate a number like this.I have tried with sequence number but couldn’t succeed since next values are not allowed inside functions. Is there any other better way to do this? 0x20180130150507252001000000 0x20180130150507252002000000 0x20180130150507252003000000 0x20180130150507253001000000 0x20180130150507253002000000 0x20180130150507253003000000 0x20180130150507253004000000